# React Native Error when `run-android`

Tags: react-native

I installed all dependencies and libs like the instructions on https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html

Everything is fine.
But when i try to run `react-native run-android` i throws me errors (see screenshot)
[image]

HAXM is installed on my machine as well.
What can i do to run it on my machine in the emulator?

SDK:
[image]

Comment: What does `adb devices` tell you? Are there any devices listed?

Comment: Yes, i have two listed actually

Comment: Try to leave only the emulator, then if it still does not work try increasing the version number in your `package.json`

Comment: There are more problems, you need to install the android SDK https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#1-install-android-studio

Comment: I have it installed. See the new screenshot in the question in a minute

Comment: In that case your ANDROID_HOME is not set so it does not know where to find it. If you're on a Mac  see https://github.com/bahattincinic/react-native-starter-kit/wiki/How-to-set-ANDROID_HOME-environment-variable-in-mac To exit vim, type :wq

Comment: "SDK location no found" export/add your sdk location path in PATH variable.

Answer (score 0):

"SDK location no found" export/add your sdk location path in PATH variable. For linux maching run following command in terminal:

```
$ export PATH="/Users/<username>/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/:$PATH"

$ react-native run-android
```

Comment: I removed all android sdk files and reinstalled the android studio. no it will work, but when i start the emulator separately before i run the command. is this the right way?

Comment: And on my other maxchine i had to copy the content from `.bash_profile` to my `.profile` and it find the SDK Location now and works fine. everything is fine now :)

Comment: ok, that means your terminal (where `react-native run-android` command is given) reads the `.profile` file. So, It is sure that SDK was not found before.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your project android folder. And create a file called "local.properties". 
Inside this file write this:

"sdk.dir={sdk_location}"

Just replace {skd_location} with the path to your android sdk. 
Then run "react-native run-android" again and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

The error simply specifies that you are not providing the sdk path to you project. So for this you need to create a **local.properties** file inside your **android folder** of the project. Inside that local.properties file just add the location for your **android SDK** as below :-

```
sdk.dir = /Users/piet/Library/Android/sdk     //this is your sdk path
```

I have provided the path from the screenshot given by you but change the path of your **android SDK** if it is different.